# How do I get individual pod hostnames in a Deployment registered and looked up in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kube-dns

I need to know all the hostnames for all the pods in a Deployment in Kubernetes.

Based on https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/, I tried:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: default-subdomain
spec:
  selector:
    name: busybox
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: foo
    port: 1234
    targetPort: 1234
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: busybox1
  labels:
    name: busybox
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: busybox
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: busybox
    spec:
      hostname: dummy <---- effect of this line 
      subdomain: default-subdomain
      containers:
      - image: busybox
        command:
          - sleep
          - "99999"
        name: busybox
        stdin: true
        tty: true
```

1. If I don't add the hostname, no pods are registered with DNS
2. If I do add the hostname value, there is only one entry in the DNS

How can I get every pod in a deployment to be registered, preferably using the pod name, and looked up by fqdn of the pod - e.g. pod_name.subdomin.namespace.svc.cluster.local?

Comment: Looks like it is not supported yet https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60789

Answer (score 13):

CoreDNS creates A and SRV records **only** for Services. It [doesn't generate pods' A records](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/issues/2409) as you may expect after reading the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#coredns-configmap-options):

> The `pods insecure` option is provided for backward compatibility with kube-dns. You can use the `pods verified` option, which returns an A record only if there exists a pod in same namespace with matching IP. The `pods disabled` option can be used if you don’t use pod records.

with the one exception:  if you create a [Headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) (when you specify `ClusterIP: None` in the Service spec)

So, here is my example of Headless Service based on your YAML:

```
NAME                TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
default-subdomain   ClusterIP      None            <none>        1234/TCP       50s
```

Here is the list of pods created by the above deployment on my cluster:

```
NAMESPACE       NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default         busybox1-76745fcdbf-4ppsf                   1/1     Running   0          18s   10.244.1.22   kube-node2-1   <none>           <none>
default         busybox1-76745fcdbf-d76q5                   1/1     Running   0          18s   10.244.1.23   kube-node2-1   <none>           <none>
```

In this case, instead of one A and one SRV record for Service's ClusterIP, we have two A and two SRV records with the same name, and IP addresses of Pods which are Endpoints for the Headless Service:

```
default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local. 5 IN A 10.244.1.22
_foo._tcp.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local. 5 IN SRV 0 50 1234 10-244-1-22.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local.
default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local. 5 IN A 10.244.1.23
_foo._tcp.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local. 5 IN SRV 0 50 1234 10-244-1-23.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local.
```

To resolve SRV records, A records also has been created for both Headless Service endpoints.

If you don't specify specify `hostname` **and** `subdomain` for pods, A records will be created with IP addresses as a hostnames:

```
10-244-1-22.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local. 5 IN A 10.244.1.22
10-244-1-23.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local. 5 IN A 10.244.1.23
```

But if you are specify both of them you will get these record as follows:

```
dummy.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local. 5 IN A 10.244.1.22
dummy.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local. 5 IN A 10.244.1.23
```

SRV records will look as follows in this case (yes, there are still two of them and they are the same):

```
_foo._tcp.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local. 5 IN SRV 0 50 1234 dummy.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local.
_foo._tcp.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local. 5 IN SRV 0 50 1234 dummy.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local.
```

CoreDNS server resolve such records in "random" way (IP addresses is changing):

```
root@ubuntu:/# ping dummy.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local -c 1 | grep PING
PING dummy.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local (10.244.1.27) 56(84) bytes of data.
root@ubuntu:/# ping dummy.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local -c 1 | grep PING
PING dummy.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local (10.244.1.27) 56(84) bytes of data.
root@ubuntu:/# ping dummy.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local -c 1 | grep PING
PING dummy.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local (10.244.1.26) 56(84) bytes of data.
root@ubuntu:/# ping dummy.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local -c 1 | grep PING
PING dummy.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local (10.244.1.27) 56(84) bytes of data.
root@ubuntu:/# ping dummy.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local -c 1 | grep PING
PING dummy.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local (10.244.1.26) 56(84) bytes of data.
root@ubuntu:/# ping dummy.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local -c 1 | grep PING
PING dummy.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local (10.244.1.26) 56(84) bytes of data.
root@ubuntu:/# ping dummy.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local -c 1 | grep PING
PING dummy.default-subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local (10.244.1.27) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

To debug it, I've used zone [transfer plugin](https://coredns.io/plugins/transfer/) of CoreDNS. To enable it you should add `transfer to *` line to **coredns** ConfigMap. You can replace * with specific IP for security. Example:

```
$ kubectl get cm coredns -n kube-system -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
 Corefile: |
   .:53 {
       errors
       health
       kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
          transfer to *   <---- enable zone transfer to anyone(don't use in production) (older coredns versions)
          transfer {      <----- ( new syntax for recent coredns versions)
              to *        <----- ( don't use older and newer transfer options in the same config! )
          }               <----- ( and check coredns pods' logs to ensure it applied correctly )
          pods insecure
          upstream
          fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
       }
       prometheus :9153
       forward . /etc/resolv.conf
       cache 30
       loop
       reload
       loadbalance
   }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
 creationTimestamp: "2019-05-07T15:44:02Z"
 name: coredns
 namespace: kube-system
 resourceVersion: "9166"
 selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/coredns
 uid: f0646569-70de-11e9-9af0-42010a9c0015
```

After that you'll be able to list all DNS records from `cluster.local` zone using the following command:

```
dig -t AXFR cluster.local any
```

More information can be found here:

- [support for zone transfer for kubernetes #1259](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/pull/1259)
- [Feature request: support zone transfers in Kubernetes middleware #660](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/issues/660)

Comment: Just a small changes with latest Kubernetes from your example, it seems SRV records returned are only one with 2 A additional sections.

Comment: This is a great answer; thanks for providing all that context! Really helped answer a few questions I had regarding CoreDNS that isn't easily found in the documentation :)

Answer (score 7):

if you want to do that consider using instead an Stateful Set  where you can go to the pod like that:

`podname-{replica-index}.{serviceName}.default.svc.cluster.local`

here an example https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/cassandra/

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that but did not want to incur the overhead of a stateful set, especially when scaling up and down.

Comment: @Nsen, have you found a way of being able to have each pod's name in the kube-dns? I'm in need of this too.

Comment: @Nsen, what's the overhead is StatefulSets support HPA same way Deployments do?