# Is it possible to configure a pod to prioritize using `hostNetwork` but still reference internal service endpoints?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-dns

I have a statefulset that I need to run using the host network, purely for performance reasons. But I also want to be able to reference service-name endpoints. Is it possible to do this? `ClusterFirstWithHostNet` does not work because it doesn't prioritize using the host's network. The `dnsConfig` [configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-policy) might be promising, but I don't know how I would configure it to do what I'm asking about.

Comment: Hi, could you please tell more about the use case that you are having? What exactly you mean by `But I also want to be able to reference service-name endpoints` Could you please provide any example for it for better understanding? Also, I'd reckon you could run into issues when trying to run multiple replicas with a `hostNetwork` when they will be scheduled on the same `Node` (port assignment).

Comment: I need to use hostNetwork purely for performance reasons. I also need to be able to reach a service internal to the cluster and due to AWS limitations, an internal NLB will not work. I could use the service static IP, but would prefer not to. These pods run background jobs so is it possible to have K8s assign it a random port on the node?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find a good solution. I had to work around it by referencing the services by their IP instead of name.

Answer (score 0):

This is a community wiki answer. Feel free to expand it.

It might be possible if the app can select random port to listen during start and change if port is busy. However, **Kubernetes is not involved in the selecting port for the application**.

`Statefulset` requires a headless service, so it doesn't have an IP and works as a set of DNS records in coredns. A record would probably contain the same IP for the replicas on the same node, but SRV record may actually provide a proper endpoint.

For further reference, please take a look at the below sources:

- [How do I get individual pod hostnames in a Deployment registered and looked up in Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54488280/how-do-i-get-individual-pod-hostnames-in-a-deployment-registered-and-looked-up-i/56778273#56778273)
- [SRV records](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#srv-records)